# Chart.js how to add a scroll effect to fit all values

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I have a chart that should display 24 hour predicted parameters data, the issue is that the dates in the X-axis are too compressed. I want to add a scroll effect and show only about 10 values before having to scroll.

[image]

The dates also push the graph to the right, making it not in the center of div.

I have tried to adding a "overflow-x: scroll" and changing the width of the graph container.
Tried to adding width to the canvas itself, but nothing seems to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      // Chart.js configuration
      var ctx = document.getElementById('energyGraph').getContext('2d');
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: [],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Voltage',
            position: 'right',
            data: [],
            borderColor: '#1D67B1',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 0,
          }]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              max: 20,
              stepSize: 1
            }
          }

        }
      });

      // Function to update energy data
      function updateEnergyData() {
        $.get("/dashboard/get_voltage/", function(data) {
          console.log(data); // Debug statement
          var rows = data;
          var lastTenRows = rows.slice(-10);
          var voltageData = lastTenRows.map(row => parseFloat(row.Voltage));
          var dateLabels = lastTenRows.map(row => new Date(row.Date).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
            hour12: false
          }));
          chart.data.labels = dateLabels.reverse();
          chart.data.datasets[0].data = voltageData.reverse();
          chart.data.datasets[0].pointStyle = 'circle';
          chart.data.datasets[0].pointRadius = 3;
          chart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor = 'blue';
          chart.options.plugins.legend.align = 'end';
          chart.update();
        });
      }
```

```css
.prediction {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 73%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.predicted-container {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100%;
}

.predicted-graph-container {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="prediction">
  <div class="predicted-container">
    <p>Predicted Energy Production</p>
    <div class="predicted-graph-container">
      <canvas id="predictedGraph"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```